# Changing Background Color of a Part of Parent Div When Hovering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have a navbar with links:

```
           <div class="navbar-inner navlinks">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a class="brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Ouvrez</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Decouvrir</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

This is made using Twitter Bootstraps, so the links sit within the navbar container and are all floated left as block elements, as you see in the typical navbar. The entire navbar has a background color of blue as defined in my `navlinks` class. It has a height significantly taller than the text of the links.

What I want is for the links to change the background color of their entire "area" when they are hovered over. Right now, when I add a hover option and a background color change, it only changes the background area over the text where the link is, which is barely noticeable. I want it to also change the color of the space above, below, and to the right of the text before the next link. I thought twitter's treatment of this as a block element would do that, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you can define the height of the nav by adding padding to the 'a' tag, instead of the 'li', and then using the regular #menu a:hover.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are really asking, but if you are adding a hover to the anchor `a:hover` maybe you just need to use the hover on link `li:hover{}`